# EventGridClient: should it be disposed?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventgrid

Azure's `EventGridClient` implements `IDisposable` interface.

Should I use dispose it after using it?

```
using (var client = new EventGridClient(_topicCredentials))
{
     await client.PublishEventsAsync(_topicHostName, events);
}
```

Or just have:

```
var client = new EventGridClient(_topicCredentials)
await client.PublishEventsAsync(_topicHostName, events);
```

In Microsoft's very basic examples is the second scenario.

I know that `HttpClient` should not be disposed if it is created by `IHttpClientFactory` because in that case connection is reused. However there's no info how `EventGridClient` manages connections.

Also, in Asp.Net Core application should it be as `Transient`, `Scoped` or `Singleton`?

Comment: see the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid/src/Generated/EventGridClient.cs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the source code, it will automatically dispose connections. See [this line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid/src/Generated/EventGridClient.cs#L397) of code in `PublishEventsWithHttpMessagesAsync` method(the [PublishEventsAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid/src/Generated/EventGridClientExtensions.cs#L41) method internally calls this method). So don't need to add `using statement`.

Comment: Thanks, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid/src/Generated/EventGridClientExtensions.cs#L43) I see that the class is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer - in a comment in [github source code here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/ed2db53441cb0ab0928b4c5d73bdaf752bfc5320/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid/src/Generated/EventGridClient.cs#L147)

> True: will dispose the provided httpClient on calling
> EventGridClient.Dispose(). False: will not dispose provided
> httpClient